# MCMC Metropolis Hastings constraint

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

> The Metropolis–Hastings algorithm can draw samples from any
> probability distribution $P(x)$, provided that we know a function
> $f(x)$ proportional to the density of $P$ and the values of $f(x)$ can
> be calculated. The requirement that $f(x)$ must only be proportional
> to the density, rather than exactly equal to it, makes the
> Metropolis–Hastings algorithm particularly useful, because calculating
> the necessary normalization factor is often extremely difficult in
> practice.

This is what is written in the wikipedia text [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm). I have three questions from this:

1. What do we mean by "The requirement that $f(x)$ must only be proportional to the density", $f(x) = cP(x)$ for all x? (*Verification*)
2. Whatever is mentioned is this the only constraint? If not what are the other constraints of selecting suitable proposal distribution?
3. What happens when the proposal distribution is not proportional to $P(x)$?

Comment: For (1), yes. For (2) and (3), I think you are confusing $f$ (a function proportional to the density $P$) with the proposal distribution (denoted $g(\cdot \mid \cdot)$ in the Wikipedia article). $g$ doesn't have to be proportional to the density $P$.

Comment: @angryavian So there is no constraint in `g`. So we can select any `g`...then how do we select specifc `g`? What `g` should I select?